# Use ini_set("memory_limit", ...) without memory allocation

Tags: php, memory

How I can use `ini_set("memory_limit","some_number")` in PHP to only set maximum memory limit for that php process, not allocate that memory?

Comment: That's what it should do, what OS are you on?

Comment: I'm running it on Linux, so, exists any function which only set memory limit?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a need to prevent allocation of the memory.

Even if the PHP interpreter would start out with a big `malloc()` (which I doubt) then still the memory is only really allocated as soon as the process starts using it.

A related phenomenon is called overcommitment, there's a few good topics about it here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

something good to read Memory Management with PHP

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=516587

If you explain more about your situation 
and 
what you exactly need,
then may be more answers you can expect